# CPU & Memory Reservation in vSphere & Numa concept

Tags: vmware-vsphere, central-processing-unit, latency, vcpu, numa

by googling/studying vSphere documentation I have found the possibility to use "Reservation" concept in vSphere.

What it is not clear to me is : CPU and Memory reservations are configured separately and work differently.

With memory reservations, the full amount of the memory is reserved and cannot be used by any other virtual machines once VM reclaims it. (It can be used just if the VM is poweroff)

With CPU reservations, the amount of CPU Mhz are reserved but they can be used by other virtual machines until needed.

Is there any way to set this CPU reservation to MAX in ovf file ?

Is there any way to force Numa node for vCPU and Memory Allocation??? I am asking becouse in the documentation it is written:

A virtual machine that has more virtual processors than the number of physical processor cores available on a single hardware node can be managed automatically. The NUMA scheduler accommodates such a virtual machine by having it span NUMA nodes. When memory is allocated to a virtual machine, the ESXi host preferentially allocates it from the home node. The virtual CPUs of the virtual machine are constrained to run on the home node to maximize memory locality.

The word "Preferentially" is worrying me..

Comment: 1) Why are you trying to mess around with ESXi's NUMA optimisation, it's very good as it is, 2) OVF isn't a VMware-specific file format yet Reservations is a VMWare-patented technology so there's no definition in the OVF file format for it and 3) Reservations are only used in contended situations - try hard not to have these.

Comment: @Chopper3, regarding 1) I need to map because I have to reach some performances and than map processes to specific core. 2) I agree with you.. in this case the answer is related the creation of flavor (if I got correctly) 3) When you use the latency sensitivity that maps the vCPU -> pCPU it is recommended to reserve 100% memory and 100% CPU otherwise (not sure) desired effects are not guaranteed. (What I expect here is that if I use "Latency Feature" the % of CPU&Memory should be automatically assigned.. I don't understand why I have to assign them..